# When were Hermann Amandus Schwarz and Marie Elizabeth Kummer married?

Tags: biographical-details

Wikipedia says that Schwarz (b. 1843) marrid Kummer in 1912 at the age of 69, had six children, then died in 1921 at the age of 78.  I'm surprised (not against!).

According to https://sprague.one-name.net/getperson.php?personID=I447193&tree=Sprague , their first child was born 1862, last child 1883, but again marriage 1912.  The source includes wikipedia.

I think something could be wrong with this data.  So is there another source independent of Wikipedia?

Comment: And I find that the first kid (Ottilie) was actually born in 1869, not 1862.  Why are these things so messed up!

Comment: is it 1843 rather than 1943?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Hahaha, thanks, updated. Now we know how the mess could have started.

Comment: What are you surprised about? His age of marriage? Or the three children?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder I was surprised that a man at his position could have six kids without marriage yet still get accepted by the German society at the time.  Turns out that he actually lived a pretty normal life.

Comment: I think these days were not as suffocating as we think they were. People back then were the same as people these days. How old was the woman he married?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder Marie Elizabeth Kummer, born 1842, was Schwarz's advisor's daughter.

Comment: So she was even older. What did he do? Was he a mathematician?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder Even? I hope you do realize that the answer below corrected the year of marriage from 1912 to 1868 (age 25-26).  Yes, he was a mathematician.

Comment: Normally a man was older than the woman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I digged out a biography written by Carathéodory ([Deutsches biographisches Jahrbuch III (1921), 236-238.](https://archive.org/details/DeutschesBiographischesJahrbuchBd031921/page/n233/)).  The marriage was in 1868.

@njuffa in the comment find that the exact date of marriage was 15 Apr. 1868, and the location was Berlin.

Comment: Specifically on April 15, 1868 in Berlin according to one source.

Comment: @njuffa but Caratheodory said that the marriage was in Halle.

Comment: That could make sense as Schwarz had a teaching position there at the time. However, Berlin also seems plausible because Ernst Kummer and his family resided there in 1868; in fact he was rector of Berlin University that year. Unfortunately I cannot really get at the source I mentioned due to Google's increasingly limited snippet view. As far as I can tell, there seem to be two treatises with research on the descendants of Moses Mendelssohn that contain information on the marriage of Schwarz and Kummer.

Comment: If you want to replicate my search use the following search terms at **Google Books**: *15. April 1868 Berlin Schwarz Kummer* The first two search results are the two treatises I referred to.

Comment: Given that you have direct access to the library at the University of Göttingen, I would think it should be fairly easy to access paper copies of the two publications "Mendelssohn Studien Band 7" and "Die Familie Mendelssohn: Stammbaum von Moses Mendelssohn bis zur siebten Generation".

Comment: @njuffa See this on Google Books.  There seems no digital archive for these documents, but I will try to read a hard copy.

Comment: 1868 as the year and Berlin as the location is confirmed by the entry for H. A. Schwarz in the [Deutsche Biographie](https://www.deutsche-biographie.de/sfz48745.html)